# Set up foreign key using Doctrine Record

Tags: sql, orm, doctrine-orm, codeigniter-2, foreign-key-relationship

The scenario:
A `client` can make many `requests`,

In the `Request` model I have:

```
public function setTableDefinition() {

        $this->hasColumn('ref_no', 'varchar', 20);
        $this->hasColumn('client_id', 'int', 11);

    }

    public function setUp() {
        $this -> setTableName('Request');
    }
```

In the db `client_id` is a foreign key referencing  `id` in client table.

How do I set up a `one to many` relationship with clients in the `setUp()` method, in both the Client Model and the Request MOdel?

Thanks,

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm try something like this at Client model:

```
public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp(); 
    $this->hasMany('Request as requests', 
        array( 
            'refClass' => 'Request', 
            'local' => 'id', 
            'foreign' => 'client_id'
        )
    ); 

}
```